# Repeat post news i click control+R post repeats php

Tags: php

The problem is when I refresh the page (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) the publication is repeated. It wants to say, for example, I want to post (news publication) (ex: text) and I click (post), ok all is good, but after I click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> the post repeats... See pictures for clarifications:

working:

[image]

the problem: no text and no picture but I have a new post:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To avoid resubmitting your form to your PHP target file you may use

```
header("Location:your_page.php");
```

in order to redirect the user.